# .htaccess only rewrite not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need a htaccess that will make the following URL:

```
domain.com/index.php?page=contact
```

Change the link into:

```
domain.com/contact
```

so if I'm doing:

```
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

The link will take me to

```
domain.com/index.php?page=contact
```

But the link shown in the link area on the browser will be:

```
domain.com/contact
```

can some one please help me?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: This is most basic of URL rewriting. Did you try to find a solution yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you, it should be placed on your root folder where your `index.php` file is located inside a file called `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

---

## What the above rule does?

First we check if the file does not exist with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Then we check if the folder does not exist with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Then we check the URL is what we are looking for, in your case `domain.com/anything` which we do with:

```
^([^/]+)$
```

The above will collect anything that is after the first `/` after `domain.com`, for example:

```
domain.com/contact
domain.com/about-us
domain.com/home
```

The right most part of our rule before the square brackets, tells what to redirect and where to:

```
index.php?page=$1
```

Which means we want to redirect whatever we collected from the previous rule, above represented as `$1` to `index.php?page=$1` which using our previous example would mean:

```
domain.com/index.php?page=contact
domain.com/index.php?page=about-us
domain.com/index.php?page=home
```

`[L]` tells we want to stop, the `L` is a flag that means `LAST`, not having any redirection flags with it and the URL not being external or a full domain name, means we want to redirect internally.

`RewriteBase /` means we are on the root folder of your domain.

`RewriteEngine On` means we want to activate `mod_rewrite` which is responsible for the rewrite redirects.

`-MultiViews` is the only relevant `Options` in this case so I will only explain that, it takes care that when a folder does not exist, it doesn't look for its replacement to be served in its place.

Comment: nope doesnt work,
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: @user2421242 that is a PHP error check your error_log file

Comment: [Fri Sep 12 07:52:49.116819 2014] [core:alert] [pid 8144:tid 972] [client ::1:14699] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/index.php?pagina=loginForm

Comment: @user2421242 You need to enable mod_rewrite on your server.

Comment: ok that works ... but the code still wont work .. it's not even sending me away .. i remain on the same page... index

Comment: @user2421242 you will have to provide more information than just that. What exactly happens when you access `domain.com/contact`? Did u change `index.php?page=$1` to `index.php?pagina=$1` as it seems your `index.php` uses `pagina` instead of `page`?

Comment: ok i'm an idiot it works, i changed the variable, thanks for being there, unfortunatly i dont have enough rep points to vote up, but i'l remember this one